# executing cmd command in powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd

hi guys i have this statement i am running in ps and works just fine

```
sc.exe \\localhost config serviceName obj= lab\user password= password type= own
```

however when trying to assign the part of it to a variable (see below) its the sc command is not being recognized by the cmd

(not working)

```
$user     = "lab\user"
$password = "password"


$sc = "\\localhost config serviceName obj= {0} password= {1} type= own" -f $user, $password


sc.exe $sc
```

appreciate the help as always !!

Comment: Type the command exactly the same way as before and press `Enter`. Why do you need the variable?

Comment: i need to pass values instead of the user and password

Comment: i added more clarification why i need to use variable there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that PowerShell is a shell that can run commands: You put the command at the beginning of the line, and you put the arguments afterward. If any of the arguments come from variables, just put them there. This is all you need to do:

```
$user     = "lab\user"
$password = "password"

sc.exe \\localhost config aie-agent-service obj= $user password= $password type= own
```

I hope it goes without saying that it is a bad idea to embed a password in any kind of program or script.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Yeah pwd will be passed via secure string. I will take your advise and simplified the script

Answer (score -1):

The .exe you're referencing may not be in your global path, or in the directory you're working out of, and therefore can't be called just by spelling out the name.  In order to reference the .exe, you'll need to "dot source" the executable file, or add the file to your path or put the file into a folder that's already in your path.  You can modify the path by clicking "My computer -> properties -> advanced -> environment variables -> Path" and adding the path to the .exe.

Comment: thanks but its not the observation i have. the sc.exe command is complaining on a syntax problem....wondering if there is an escaping issue